# Random GameObjects Comes Wrong Rotate

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to do a 3d android game in Unity with c#. I put random barriers and code is works well. But problem is the barriers rotate comes wrong, I want to see from the front but they are coming from the side. How can I rotate them front? And how to fix overlap two barriers?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Are your barriers meshes ? Do they have colliders ? if you see their side, can't you rotate them by 90° to fix it ?

Comment: Hi! Thank you :) I only see them in game scene. I put spheres,  barriers come on them. But spheres doesn't have colliders.  I cannot see the barriers in scene, when I try to fix rotation in game scene, they doesn't come same rotate when I play it second time. They are come again with side rotate

Comment: @OzdenOzbek if you change something while your game is running, Unity reverts it when you stop your game. If you need to move something, move it when the game isn't playing. If you are using `Instantiate()` to spawn from prefabs during gameplay, you can rotate the prefab before playing or specify the `rotation` in `Instantiate(Object yourPrefab, Vector3 positionToSpawnAt, Quaternion rotation)` `https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html`